# How to add my APP for Apple notes extension

Tags: nativescript, info.plist

I want to add a plist config  for nativescript project. But I can't find the way  to add the notes extension.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for your plist file? If so, check App_Resources/ios. You can edit it there.